# Convert time to time zone without changing the actual time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Time object that I'm trying to change the time zone for, but I don't want to change the actual value. For example, when I convert 11:00:00 UTC to MDT, it becomes 5:00 MDT:

```
[6] pry(#<ScheduledDate>)> Time.parse("#{start_date} #{first_allowed_time}")
=> 2020-09-05 11:00:00 +0000
[7] pry(#<ScheduledDate>)> Time.parse("#{start_date} #{first_allowed_time}").in_time_zone("Mountain Time (US & Canada)")
=> Sat, 05 Sep 2020 05:00:00 MDT -06:00
[8] pry(#<ScheduledDate>)>
```

How can I simply add a time zone to the UTC time without actually changing its time?

Answer (score 2):

The `Time` object [always stores times in UTC](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html). It's generally best to store and manipulate times in UTC, and handle the timezone separately when displaying the time. So your `Time` object will always be in UTC, though you can display it in different zones. This uses Rails' [`TimeWithZone` class](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html), but you shouldn't instantiate those directly. Using them through helpers like `in_time_zone` is better.

If you need to store a time zone, storing the time zone name is a good solution. These are [defined by IANA](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html) and [supported by Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-iso8601).